# How to avoid update the original object when I update the object in other var?

Tags: javascript

I have this original array objects:

```
const students=[
  { "name": "sean"},{"name":"paula"}
];
```

I am trying to update the object where `student.name==="sean"` to `"jason"`

I want to avoid update the original array object

```
console.log(students); // should be {"name": "jason"},{"name": "paula"}
console.log(findStudent); //output is {"name":"jason"} (desired result)
```

```js
const students=[
  { "name": "sean"},{"name":"paula"}
];

const findStudent= students.find((student)=>student.name==="sean");
findStudent.name="jason";
console.log(findStudent); //output is {"name":"jason"} (desired result)
console.log(students); // output is {"name": "jason"},{"name": "paula"} (wrong result)
```

, how to avoid it?

Comment: What is the desired result for students?

Comment: @Ando `console.log(students);  {"name": "sean"},{"name": "paula"} `

Comment: try doing this `var updatedStudents = students.map((student) => { if(student.name === "sean") { student.name = "jason"} return student }` then use the `updatedStudents` or assign it to `students`